# Can awk use field identifiers also for shell strings (variables)?

Tags: shell, awk, string, variable

Well, this apparently is not possible the way I'm trying it.

This alternate approach to obtain **bar** as a resulting string works, though:

```
#!/bin/bash

path1=/usr/tmp/foo/bar/baz

awk -F/ '{print $5}' <<< "$path1"
```

So far so good, but what if I want to do without the `<<<` operator as well as those notorious `echo | ...` pipes?
In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is passing `path1` as a variable with the `-v pa="$path1"` directive *and* using both the field separator `-F/` and the field identifiers (e. g. `$5`) to parse the `awk`-**internal** `pa` variable, which got its value assigned from the **external** `path1` shell variable.
Can this be done "inside" `awk`, too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with the `-v` option or with the `var=value` arguments to `awk` is that they can't be used for arbitrary data since ANSI C escape sequences (like `\n`, `\b`...) are expanded in them (and with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [if the value starts with `@/` and ends in `/`, it's treated as a regexp type of variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)).

The alternative is to use the `ARGV` or `ENVIRON` `awk` arrays:

```
awk -F / 'BEGIN{$0 = ARGV[1]; print $5}' "$path1"
```

Or:

```
export path1
awk -F / 'BEGIN{$0 = ENVIRON["path1"]; print $5}'
```

Or:

```
path1="$path1" awk -F / 'BEGIN{$0 = ENVIRON["path1"]; print $5}'
```

Now, if all you want is split a shell variable, you may not need `awk`.

In all POSIX shells:

```
IFS=/; set -f
set -- $path1
printf '%s\n' "$5"
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks interesting as well! Just one thing always confuses me again: `awk` expects a *file* after the `'...'`, right? So why does it accept a string in this case without complaining? -- To your second approach: As I normally use *local* variables in my bash scripts, I normally do not make them available from outside using `export`. And not to be forgotten: these variables will have to be un`export`ed again to reduce clutter, whilst local variables are destroyed after the script ends (or exits prematurely).

Comment: @syntaxerror, See the 3rd variant then, or use ARGV. If there's only a BEGIN section, files or standard input are not read.

Comment: Nice, thanks, I'll remember that from now on! Besides, your logic also works the other way round: that is to say, if you do NOT set a BEGIN section and use a variable like this here (and not a file), `awk` may "stall" and you have to `CTRL-C` it to get back to your shell prompt. Didn't happen to me only once when I did my first `awk` steps some moons ago.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use ENVIRON. I tried that but didn't realize to drop the `$` bit from the variable name. Very nice and elegant solutions!

Answer (score 3):

You could split `pa` into an array

```
awk -F'/' -v pa=$path1 'BEGIN{split(pa, arr, FS); print(arr[5]); exit}'
```

Comment: That fails if `$path1` contains blanks. May fail if it contains wildcard characters or backslashes.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, good point. And +1 for your solution that addresses these issues

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can pass environment variables into an `awk` script/command:

#### Method #1

This gets the shell to expand the variable, `$path1`, prior to running the `awk` command.

```
$ echo $path1
/usr/tmp/foo/bar/baz
$ awk -F'/' 'END{a="'$path1'"; split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' /dev/null
bar
```

#### Method #2

Pass env. variable in as a awk variable, `a`.

```
$ awk -F '/' 'END{split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' a=$path1 /dev/null
bar
```

#### Method #3

Explicitly pass `awk` a variable using the `-v` switch.

```
$ awk -F'/' -v a=$path1 'END{split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' /dev/null
bar
```

#### Debugging

You can enable the shell's verbosity by setting `set -x` before running any of these commands to see what's going on. Here's method #2 as an example:

```
$ set -x
$ awk -F '/' 'END{split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' a=$path1 /dev/null
+ awk -F / 'END{split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' a=/usr/tmp/foo/bar/baz /dev/null
bar
```

The above shows `set -x` being executed followed by the awk line. You can see that when executed the variable `a` has the value of `$path1` already expanded when it executes.

Another example, this time method #1:

```
$ awk -F'/' 'END{a="'$path1'";split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' /dev/null
+ awk -F/ 'END{a="/usr/tmp/foo/bar/baz";split(a,arr,FS); print(arr[5])}' 
bar
```

Here you can see that the shell is definitely expanding the `$path1` variable prior to executing `awk`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your efforts! Indeed, but there is obviously no way you can make *direct* use of those `$3`, `$4` field identifiers. You will always have to work around it by using `split()` and arrays. -- However, if I had the possibility of using field identifiers, it would make the line appear significantly shorter for sure (which is always a criteria to care upon :))

Comment: Method 1: not sure why you use both a BEGIN and END section, may fail (possibly badly) if $path1 contains double quotes, blanks, backslashes, globbing characters. For instance, try with `path1='";system("rm\040-rf\040~");"'`

Comment: Method2 2 and 3: may fail if `$path1` contains blanks or wildcards (as `$path1` is still not quoted) or backslashes.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks I've removed the BEGIN section.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
basename "$(dirname "$path1")"
```

or, if your shell supports process substitution and you need to use `awk`:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $5}' <(printf '%s\n' "$path1")
```

Comment: To your first line: OK for this purpose, but these examples should not be taken too literally. I usually use these with the intention to do something way more complex later. I was just asking because I needed the right *technique* to get string variables from outside parsed inside `awk`. -- To your second line: This is not much different from my `<<<` approach. This will as well have to be done from outside `awk`. But thanks anyway for your input.